# Where does VS save, which projects are loaded at the start?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have trouble to start a solution in VS. I think it is due to Windows.Form file that was opened in the design mode, since I get the following message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'blabla' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I hope that if only the StartPage would show up, the problem would be solved. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Startup (Under Environment)

Answer (score 0):

After several retries, it was also possible to close that window and save everything so that the broken window was not loaded after the next restart.